# Adding pageYOffset value to a div's position as page scrolls down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone please tell me how do I add pageYOffset property to a div's top value as the scroll takes place.

I want to make a div move along with scroll, for that I'll have to add pageYoffet value to div's top value, div is positioned relatively.

Here's link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/a2tkorno/6/)

Here's html code:

```
<div class="slider-one slide" style="background-image:url('http://208.131.135.54/~imacre17/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/homeslide1a.png'); height: 100%; background-size: cover;" class="slider-background-image' ">
    <div class="slide-inner-container">
        <div class="slider-content">

        </div><!-- /.slider-content -->
    </div><!-- /.slide-inner-container -->
</div><!-- /.slide -->
```

I would like to add the value to div '.slider-content'.

I know how to find it out at any given point but I'm not sure on how to add it on the fly as page scroll happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: `position: fixed` looks like an easy solution but I want a js solution because fixed position will interfere with some other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, do you want to set the div fixed to the top at all times? if that's the case, you would need to set slider-content to position fixed  and top should be set to 0 like so:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

Here's the fiddle working; http://jsfiddle.net/a2tkorno/7/

Edit:

This is the Javascript you will need for this to work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.slider-content').css('top', window.scrollY);
});
```

And apply these styles to .slider-content:

```
.slider-content {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 40;
}
```

Let me know if this works better now.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the answer but position: fixed is not going to solve the thing, I want to add some more functionality later which will not work with fixed position. I will update the question.

Comment: @chandan ah, gotcha, give me a second so I edit my answer to what you want to do then.